# Can't connect Azure Search index to Snowflake database via the power query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Error detecting index schema from datasource: "Data source type 'powerquery is not supported

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LonnB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are connecting after requesting access to Power Query connectors. You will be provided instructions on how to use them from the portal.
Power Query connector support is currently in a gated public preview.
For instructions please visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-how-to-index-power-query-data-sources